# Tabs in StringBuilder don't work when sending an e-mail (Android)!

Tags: android, email, tabs, formatting

Bit of a weird on this; I my app I am using StringBuilder to build Strings to create an e-mail.

Now what I am trying to do is send the e-mail with parts of text tabbed (the text is to be transferred into a Word Document and this would save a lot of editing).

So in my code I am writing code to include the tabs, for example:

```
message.append(component).append("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t").append(risk).append("\r\n");
```

I use following code to construct the e-mail:

```
private void sendEmail(String recipient, String subject, String message) { 
    try { 
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");          

        if (recipient != null)  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient}); 
        if (subject != null)    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 
        if (message != null)    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); 

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...")); 

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
        // cannot send email for some reason 
    } 
}
```

So when I look at the e-mail before sending, the tabs seem to have worked, but when I receive the e-mail, they are not there.  Boo.

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have tried your code, it seems tab symbols trimmed while email sends.
Also tried this way and it works fine (in gmail), but it ugly solution

```
 private String tab(){
    return "    "; // return four space characters
}

message.append(tab()+tab+tab());
```

Comment: Nice work around, but it's a shame there is not a way to solve the issue.  I'll leave it a little time to see if anyone has any other ideas and if not I'll tick your answer.  Thanks for the response.